# Add a foreign key id to a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm building a simple bug tracker tool, but I have a problem.

When you create a new project, you get redirected to the project page, there you can add a new bug to the project.
You have a 'projects' table and a 'bugs' table in the MySQL db (phpmyadmin).

The new bug will be added in the 'bugs' table, but how can I add the project id to the bugs table?

I already added 'fk_project_id' as a foreign key to the 'bugs' table.

this is a code snippet from the project page (here, you select all the info from the project):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bugslap");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM projects where projects_id = $id");
mysqli_close($con);`
```

and here you will be redirected to a form where you can add a new bug:

```
<a href="newbug.php">add a new bug</a>
```

when you submit the form, it will run this script (bug.class.php):

```
$name        = $_POST['name'];
$descr       = $_POST['description'];   
$leader      = $_POST['leader'];    
$img         = $_POST['img'];

$sql="INSERT INTO bugs (name, description, leader, img, registration_date,fk_project_id)
VALUES ('$name', '$descr', '$leader', '$img', NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if($result){
header('Location: ../projectpage.php');
}
else {
echo "Oops, there is something wrong. Try again later.";
}

mysql_close();
```

Then you should be redirected to the project page, where the bug is added to the project. I want to show all the bug info (description,image,...) on this project page.

Comment: Before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Always use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to properly encode all values used in your query. Things like `$id` have no business being in your query string, and adding arbitrary `$_POST` data is a very, very bad habit to get in to.

Comment: @tadman I'll solve this, but first I need an answer to the question :p.

Comment: Your problem might be mixing `mysqli` calls, which you should be using, with `mysql_query` calls, which you should **not** be using. It's challenging to build an application like this from scratch. Is there any reason you're not using a [popular PHP framework](http://webrevisions.com/tutorials/php-framework-the-best-php-framework-for-2013/) instead of this ad-hoc approach?

Comment: @tadman it's a school assignment, can't use a php framework :(... If you could help me, that would be rad!

Comment: You should be using only `mysqli` if you have that available. Why are there calls using `mysql_query`? Is that even connected? These two libraries use their own incompatible connections. You're also not checking for errors produced by your query calls, which is a must if you want to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the project id to the newbug.php page; for example with a GET parameter.
Then you can easily fetch it from newbug.php and pass it on to your class.